# Keep the citation number in the document incremnted consecutively

Tags: bibtex, bibliographies, citing

I have use the `\bibliographystyle{ieeetr}` before as style for my Bibliography but when I wanted to add URL to the article entry, The ieeetr style did not recognize the URL. Therefore I changed the style to `plainurl` where I have lost the option to keep the citation number in the document incremented consecutively. Is there anyway to  reach both option in one style or to fix it?

Currently I am getting t in the document this sequence of the citation number `3,1,2` and I want to get `1,2,3`.

**tex code**

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{bibliography.bib}
@article{recordingData2,
  author = {Leon Stenneth and Ouri Wolfson and Philip S. Yu and Bo Xu},
  title = {Transportation Mode Detection using Mobile Phones and {GIS} Information},
  journal = {ACM DL},
  year = {2011},
  pages = {3},
} 
@misc{waze,
   author = {androidcommunity.com},
   title = {Waze traffic app updates with {Foursquare} and {Yelp} integration},
   howpublished = {\url{http://androidcommunity.com/waze-traffic-app-updates-with-foursquare-and-yelp-integration-20120131/}},
   note = {Accessed: 29.09.2015}
}
@article{recordingData,
  author = {Rudolf Giffinger},
  title = {Smart cities Ranking of {European} medium-sized cities},
  journal = {Report of Centre of Regional Science},
  year = 2007,
  month = "October",
  url  = {http://www.smart-cities.eu/download/smart_cities_final_report.pdf},
  note = "Accessed: Nov.~6, 2015",
  pages = {11}
}
\end{filecontents}

\documentclass[
    11pt,english,twoside,a4paper,headsepline,footsepline
    ]{scrbook}

%%\usepackage{a4}   
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{cite}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage[hyphens]{url}
\usepackage[bookmarks=true,bookmarksopen=true,
           bookmarksnumbered=true,
           colorlinks=true,citecolor=black,linkcolor=black                 
           ]{hyperref}

\begin{document}

        \cite{recordingData2}, \cite{waze}, \cite{recordingData}
        \bibliographystyle{plainurl}
        \bibliography{bibliography}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

I suggest you make two changes:

- Don't load the `cite` package; instead, load the `natbib` package with the option `numbers` (since you appear to use numeric citation call-outs):

  ```
  \usepackage[numbers]{natbib}
  ```
- Use the `unsrtnat` bibliography style instead of the `plainurl` style:

  ```
  \bibliographystyle{unsrtnat}
  ```

After making these modifications, be sure to run LaTeX, BibTeX, and LaTeX twice more to fully propagate all changes.